# Two cells in a TableView row

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to have 2 UITableViewCells in every row in a UITableView.

I know how to create a custom cell but I don't see an option to to make a cell half the width of the tableView.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you have to make 2 tableViews

Comment: How will i scroll both of them together?

Comment: You could detect when one is scrolled and scroll the other one along but that doesn't seem to be a good approach

Comment: you _do not_ want two cells in a tableview's row, you _do_ want to implement a collection view with two columns. piece of cake.

Comment: haha, @holex is right 

Comment: What about using UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

You should not able to create two cells in single row.If you want to customise like that better to go UICollectionView.

check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html